# file to store the bash settings for a virtual terminal

Tags: bash, console, terminal, debian

When You press [ALT+F1...F6] on Linux machine You see "virtual terminal" usually.
When I log in via virtual terminal on my Debian machine - bash does not implement settings from $HOME/.bashrc and $HOME/.profile files!
What file must I use to place bash settings for virtual terminal?

I tried to debug this:

```
    $ strace  -e open  bash --login 2>&1 | grep -P "\.bash|profile"

    open("/etc/profile", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
    open("/etc/profile.d/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
    open("/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
    open("/home/ruslan/.bash_profile", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/home/ruslan/.bash_login", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
    exit
    open("/home/ruslan/.bash_logout", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
    open("/etc/bash.bash_logout", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

~/.profile - not present!

Comment: Very strange. Is your shell set to bash?

Comment: I think yes.  `echo $SHELL - /bin/bash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you computer boots it starts [init](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Init_and_inittab) and checks a file (e.g. `/etc/inittab`) for processes to start. Usually this file contains a few lines like the one below.

`c5:5:respawn:/sbin/agetty 57600 tty2 xterm-256color`

Loose translation:
When in run level 5 (multiuser mode), start agetty (log-in process), on console 2 (ALT-F2). If the process dies (e.g. after you log out) start a new one (respawn).

If you log in that that agetty then you will start a log-in shell. This can be bash. **It can be another shell**. (You can set the default shell with `chsh`).

If you have bash configured as default shell then it will start bash and look in these places: (note, this files are check when bash is invoked **specifically as a log-in shell**)

- /etc/profile
- ~/.bash_profile
- ~/.bash_login
- ~/.profile

As you can see this includes the $HOME/.profile you mentioned earlier, but not $HOME/.bashrc

In this case of an interactive but **non-login shell**, bash checks `/etc/bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`.

I suspect that last part answers your question. (Test it with `bash -l` or `bash --login`).